# Use postmeta in wordpress shortcode

Tags: wordpress

Trying to get my post meta from posts using shrotcodes and then displaying it on the content.This is the code that's trying to do this:

```
$string = '';
$custom_content = get_post_custom($post->ID);

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
      $content = get_the_content();
      $bonus = $custom_content["bonus"];

      $string .= $content . $bonus . '<br>'; 
  endwhile;
}
return $string;
```

It's not working as the custom content returns empty. Whats wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: We're going to need a little bit more information here. Where is this code defined (reason I ask is because you've used the global `$post`, but did you mean to access the global?)? Secondly what's the content of `$my_query`? Also what do you mean by shortcodes - i.e. custom defined shortcodes or shortcodes that a plugin has defined (and if so, which one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you got the shortcode idea, you should read some info about [`add_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) also you can use [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to retriev the metadata from the database.

Here is an example on how you can achieve this but this will only work with the main loop (as default):

```
<?php
//you can put this code in functions.php or you can build a plugin for it
function metadata_in_content($attr) {
//this is the function that will be triggerd when the code finds the proper shortcode in the content; $attr is the parameter passed throw the shortcode (leave null for now)
    global $wpdb, $wp_query;
    //we need global $wpdb to query the database and to get the curent post info
    if (is_object($wp_query->post)) {
        $post_id = $wp_query->post->post_id;// here we save the post id
        $metadata = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single ); // here we get the needed meta, make sure you place the correct $key here, also if you don't want to get an array as response pass $single as "true"
        return $metadata; // this finally replaces the shortcode with it's value
    }
}
add_shortcode('insert_metadata', 'metadata_in_content');
//the above code hooks the metadata_in_content function to the [insert_metadata] shortcode
?>
```

Now all it's left to do is to place [insert_metadata] in the post content and things should work.